# DIV is too tall for the text inside

Tags: css, html, text

Hey I've been having some trouble figuring out this problem. I have a DIV that I want to be only as tall as the text within it, but for some reason it insists on being a little bit taller. Here's what it looks like:

http://admiraltheband.com/index3956.html

I want the red border to hug around the text instead of being taller. Here's the codes.

```css
/*CSS:*/

    p {
            color:#fff;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            vertical-align:middle;
    }
    
    .separator {
         height:48px;
            width:1px;
            background-color: #000;
         margin:0 auto;
         padding:0;
    }
    
    .links {
         overflow:auto;
         margin:0 auto;
         width:375px; 
    }

    .toptext {
         color:black;
         font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Times, serif;
         font-weight:bold;
         font-size:40px;
         margin:0 auto;
         padding:0;
         vertical-align:middle;
    }
    
    .facebook {
         float:left;
         text-align:center;
         vertical-align:middle;
         /* margin-top:-4px; */
         padding:0;
         border:1px solid red;
    }
    
    .youtube {
         float:right;
         text-align:center;
         vertical-align:middle;
         /* margin-top:-4px; */
         padding:0;
         border:1px solid red;
    }
    
    a {
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
    }
```

```html
HTML:

    <div class="links">
        
                <div class="facebook">
                 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/admiralmusic" 
                    target="_blank"><p class="toptext">Facebook</p></a>
                </div>


                <div class="youtube">
                 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXCmjrxe-ySnvigewJvGbfQ" 
                    target="_blank"><p class="toptext" style="margin:0;padding:0;">YouTube</p></a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="separator">
                </div>
                
    </div>
```

I've been putting 0 padding and 0 margin on the paragraphs and all the parent elements, but to no avail. I commented out the negative margin which I might end up using to get things aligned. I'm just curious as to why this DIV is stretching a little bit.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try and replicate the problem using the snippet.

Comment: What do you mean? Where is the issue?

Comment: This will make it more clear:

http://admiraltheband.com/index3956.html

I want the red border to hug around the text instead of being taller.

Comment: Line-height is what is causing this.

Comment: There are probably several old questions with good answers about this. There is no simple answer, because the spacing depends on font design (and on `line-height`, but that’s the simple part).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `line-height: 1;` to your classes `.facebook` and `.youtube`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `line-height` attribute same as the height of your `p`

```
.toptext{
   line-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a little something to play around with its hard to get to the root of the problem. However you seem to have everything at 0px. There are some defaults paddings, margins etc on browser that can be reset using the following.

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add negative margins to the one class:

```
.toptext {
color: black;
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Times, serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 40px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100%;
margin-top: -4px;
margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

The last two css rules I have added. You can easily edit them to get the red border closer or further away.

```
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
```

[image]

PS: You need to remove the `style="margin:0;padding:0;"`inside the p.toptext for "YouTube" for the above change to have effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `overflow` code from `.links` class and put `height:43px;`to `.separator`class.

Thank You